# Discord.py Check if Channel is a DM

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a command that i only want to be executable through a DM with the bot. The current code makes it possible to send the command to any channel, i want to prevent this.

```
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if discord.ChannelType.private:
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

I've also tried: **discord.ChannelType == discord.ChannelType.private** & **discord.DMChannel**

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted or help improving them.

Answer (score 16):

In discord.py, direct message channel objects come from [class `discord.channel.DMChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=dmchannel#discord.DMChannel). We can check if an object comes from a class using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```py
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: This is by far, the most pythonic way to see if a channel is object `DMChannel`. Most straight-forward answer. +1.

Comment: I believe this `discord.channel.DMChannel` has been changed to `discord.DMChannel`, so you should update your answer.

Comment: ^That's correct, and as of late a [decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) that checks this for you now exists and is in my opinion a better way to go about this - though it raises a special exception

Answer (score 9):

Add a [`dm_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.dm_only) check:

```
@client.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: In my experience this answer is far better compared to the others, although it might be good to mention that this raises a commands.NoPrivateMessage exception, which needs to be handled/suppressed

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if ctx.guild is False:
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use discord.py version 1.3.3 and `if ctx.guild is False:` doesn't work for me.
In my opinion you should use the discord class [discord.ChannelType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20channeltype#discord.ChannelType), that's what it is there for.
The following code works for me

```
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if ctx.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private:
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#use this code if you are using @client.event 
import discord

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("register"):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
      await message.author.send("registration mode coming soon!")
  else:
    await message.channel.send("pls register in bot dm")
client.run(bot token)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, arg):
    if ctx.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ChannelType

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.