# discord.py dm command issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So with my dm command, Whenever Someone dms me with it, it picks up messages sent in the server from that person and I tried to make it ignore message sent in the server but it either doesn't work at all or gives an error saying argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. Is there a way to make it only detect messages from the member's dms?

here is my code:

```
async def dm(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send("Mention a member to dm.")
  elif member == client.user:
    await ctx.send("Mention another member to dm.")
    return
  elif member.bot == True:
    await ctx.send("Mention another member to dm.")
    return
  elif member == ctx.author:
    await ctx.send("You can't dm yourself.")
    return
  else:
    await ctx.send("Enter your message now.")
    def check(m):
      return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
    def check2(m):
      return m.author.id == member.id
    while True:
      try:
        message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout = 30)
        if message.author == client.user:
          return
        elif message.content in ctx.guild:
          return
        else:
          await ctx.author.send("Sent Message")
          await member.send(f"[Type a message to respond to DM Partner] **DM Partner says:** {message.content}")
      except TimeoutError:
        await ctx.author.send("You took too long to respond")
        await member.send(f"DM Partner took too long to respond.")
        return False
      try:
        message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check2, timeout = 30)
        if message.author == client.user:
          return
        else:
          await member.send("Sent Message")
          await ctx.author.send(f"[Type a message to respond] DM Partner says: {message.content} ")
      except:
        await ctx.author.send("Your Dm Partner took too long to respond.")
        await member.send("You took too long to respond.")
        return False
```

Comment: I do not really understand your problem here... "*it picks up messages sent in the server from that person and I tried to make it ignore message sent in the server*" - This is very confusing. What are you trying to do? Do you just want to wait for the authors message after executing the command? Is the command also picking up other messages from the server from other users? I guess you want to say that your `check` function does not really makes sense?

Comment: What I meant was if the member the bot is dming says anything outside of the bot's dms, it will send that as the message. I want it to only send the message if the message is in the bot's dms.

Comment: Is this helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987677/discord-py-check-if-channel-is-a-dm

Comment: yes thank you so much